# Use Linphone in Armv7s, Armv7 and arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, libraries, linphone

I have created a project that uses linphone successfully in armv7 and arm64. When I try to add armv7s files included at the link below, it doesn't let me support arm64. How can I easily add it?

https://github.com/onmyway133/linphone-iphone/tree/master/liblinphone-sdk/armv7s-apple-darwin

Comment: What exactly happens "When I try to add armv7s  ... it doesn't let me support arm64"?

Comment: once I added armv7s to my archit list, I would get errors saying that certain .a files weren't build for armv7s. When I changed them all out, then it would tell me that those files were compatible with arm64

Comment: Please edit the question with more detailed information. With what I do you "changed them all out"? In terminal, check the .a files you put in place: `file /path/to/my.a` and let us know the output.

Comment: I feel like the original question is pretty straight forward and to the point. I need Linphone to run on all three architectures. Then I explained that I got the armv7s version from the link listed and switched them out with my original Linphone version but still got errors. That is pretty much it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build liblinphone SDK for armv7s as well by running:

```
./prepare.py arm64 armv7s armv7 [your other options]
make
```

But I'm afraid armv7s is **not** supported by Linphone yet, so you won't be able to do so. You should try reach them on their [mailing list](https://www.google.fr/search?q=linphone+dev+mailing+list&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XydYWN97xu_wB4OLntAN&gws_rd=ssl).